# AddToAny share statistics with google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get AddToAny sharing to show up in Analytics. I understand that with Universal Analytics clicks on the AddToAny buttons should show up under Social>Plug-ins>"Social Source and Action". However, I am getting no reports.

Details: I am using Google Tag Manager V2 to load the Universal Analytics code. Works fine for everything except AddToAny reporting above.
Any thoughts? Is there some custom coding I need to add to Google Tag Manager or special setup in Analytics or in the AddToAny plugin settings??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GTM's linkClick event listener combined with gtm.elementClasses. Then use a custom macro to grab the text of whatever is being clicked.

1. Create tag called `gtm.linkClick`. It's tag type is 'Link Click Listener'. You can check the 'Wait for Tags' checkbox, if you'd like. Set the firing rule for All Pages.
2. Create a macro called `gtm.elementClasses`. It's an Auto-Event Variable. The Variable type is Element Classes.
3. Create another macro called `gtm.elementText`. It also is an Auto-Event Variable. The Variable type is Element Text.
4. Create another macro called gtm.elementUrl. It also is an Auto-Event Variable. The Variable type is Element URL.
5. Create an new macro called `event`. The macro type is `Custom Event`.
6. Create your AddToAny social tag. Track type 'Social'. Your Network could use `{{gtm.elementText}}` macro as the name of the network, or if you have other social widgets, you could prefix the network with AddToAny - `{{gtm.elementText}}`. Set the action to `click` or something, and provide a action target, use `{{gtm.elementUrl}}`.
7. Set the rule as `{{event}}` equals `gtm.linkClick`, and `{{gtm.elementClasses}}` contains `a2a_i`. *Your class might vary. You'll have to look it up by doing an inspect element on one of the social links in the AddToAny div.*
8. Save and publish.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it on Tag Manager V2, I'll let you know, the problem is that AddToAny button are not recognized as "link click" event.

Answer (score 0):

Most Social plugins depend on the web property using the default tracker name so that they can use a standard ga('send', 'social'...); hit.

By default GTM gives each hit a unique tracker name, generally something like gtm1437748828406.  This means that the standard tracker is not initiated so when the plugin tries to send the event there will be a 'Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined' error (you can check this using the GA debugger plugin on Chrome).

You can force your GTM tags to use the default tracker by going to the Advanced Configuration settings and checking the 'Set Tracker Name' box then leaving the box blank.

Note, however, that this the use of named trackers is highly discouraged in GTM.  There is more information on why here:

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2574372?hl=en#TrackerName